Group whose order is a power of prime has a tower of normal subgroup

Let $p$ be a prime and $G$ a finite group with $|G| = p^n$. I want to prove that there exists a tower of subgroups
$$G_0 \subset G_1 \subset \dots \subset G_n = G$$
such that $|G_k| = p^k$ for all $0 \leq k \leq n$, and that $G_k$ is normal in $G$.
I have an idea which I write below, but this idea is somewhat cumbersome and splits into cases and I was wondering if there is a cleaner proof. Anyways, my proof is:
Let $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$, then we know that $|Z(G)| > 1$ (the order of $G$ is a power of a prime), suppose that $|Z(G)| = p^t$ for some $t > 0$.
Case 1: $Z(G) \neq G$. We can use induction on $n$. For $n = 1$ this is trivial as $G$ is cyclic. Now take $H := G/Z(G)$. Both $H$ and $Z(G)$ have size smaller than $p^n$ so we can apply the induction hypothesis to get $Z_0 \subset Z_1 \subset Z_2 \subset \cdots \subset Z(G)$ and $Z(G) = H_0 \subset H_1 \subset H_2 \subset \cdots \subset H$ such that $|Z_i| = p^i$ and $|H_j|= p^j$. Now we can build, from every $H_j$, a subgroup of $G$ by taking all the elements in all of the cosets of $H_j$. This will give us a subgroup of $G$ of size $|H_j|\times |Z(G)| = p^{j+ t}$, so we can "stick" these groups right after the groups we got from the decomposition of $Z(G)$, to get the final conclusion.
Case 2: $Z(G) = G$ hence $G$ is abelian. We can use induction again, but differently. First find an element $g$ of order $p$, then look at $H := G/\langle g\rangle$. Then again both $G$ and $\langle g\rangle$ have smaller sizes so we can use induction and a similar idea as the first case.
More precise question: in both cases we used induction, but the idea was different. We couldn't use the second idea in the first case, because if $G$ is not abelian, we don't know if $\langle g\rangle$ is normal so we can't divide by it. Similarly in the first case we have to assume (in the way it is written now) that $Z(G) \neq G$. Is it necessary? Is there a cleaner proof?

I don't know about "cleaner proof", but certainly others have tried. I found this post here, and there are certainly more. Or this post.

You can use induction directly; $Z(G)$ is nontrivial, so it contains an element $g$ of order $p$, and $\langle g\rangle$ is normal. Now apply the induction hypothesis to $G/\langle g\rangle$ and lift the series to $G$. It doesn't matter whether $Z(G)=G$ or not.

There is no reason to separate the cases. You can achieve this simply by arguing inductively.
We prove the result by induction on $n$. If $n=1$, there is nothing to do.
Assume the result holds for groups of order $p^k$, and let $G$ have order $p^{k+1}$.
We know that $Z(G)$ is nontrivial, and hence an abelian $p$-group. Therefore, there is a central element $g\in Z(G)$ of order $p$; since $g$ is central, $\langle g\rangle$ is normal in $G$, of order $p$. Now consider $H=G/\langle g\rangle$. This is a $p$-group of  order $p^k$, so by the induction hypothesis there is a chain of subgroups
$$1=H_0 \lt H_1\lt\cdots\lt  H_k=H,$$
where $H_i$ has order $p^i$ and is normal in $H$.
By the Isomorphism theorems, each of these groups is of the form $G_i/\langle g\rangle$ for some subgroup of $G$. Since the correspondence is inclusion-preserving and normality preserving, we obtain subgroups of $G$,
$$ 1 = \langle g\rangle = G_0< G_1\lt G_2\lt\cdots \lt G_k = G,$$
with each $G_i$ normal in $G$. The order of $G_i/\langle g\rangle = H_i$ is $p^i$, and $\langle g\rangle$ has order $p$, so $|G_i| = p^{i+1}$. This gives the desired chain of normal subgroups of $G$.
